# Parsing juxtaposition-based, indentation-aware syntax using Text.Parsec.Layout

Tags: parsing, haskell, indentation, parsec, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse a small language with Haskell-like syntax, using [`parsec-layout`](https://github.com/luqui/parsec-layout). The two key features that don't seem to interact too well with each other are:

- Function application syntax is juxtaposition, i.e. if `F` and `E` are terms, `F E` is the syntax for `F` applied to `E`.
- Indentation can be used to denote nesting, i.e. the following two are equivalent:

  ```
  X = case Y of
    A -> V
    B -> W

  X = case Y of A -> V; B -> W
  ```

I haven't managed to figure out a combination of skipping and keeping whitespace that would allow me to parse a list of such definitions. Here's my simplified code:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding (space, runP)
import Text.Parsec.Layout
import Control.Monad (void)

type Parser = Parsec String LayoutEnv

data Term = Var String
          | App Term Term
          | Case Term [(String, Term)]
          deriving Show

name :: Parser String
name = spaced $ (:) <$> upper <*> many alphaNum

kw :: String -> Parser ()
kw = void . spaced . string

reserved :: String -> Parser ()
reserved s = try $ spaced $ string s >> notFollowedBy alphaNum

term :: Parser Term
term = foldl1 App <$> part `sepBy1` space
  where
    part = choice [ caseBlock
                  , Var <$> name
                  ]

    caseBlock = Case <$> (reserved "case" *> term <* reserved "of") <*> laidout alt

    alt = (,) <$> (name <* kw "->") <*> term

binding :: Parser (String, Term)
binding = (,) <$> (name <* kw "=") <*> term

-- https://github.com/luqui/parsec-layout/issues/1
trim :: String -> String
trim = reverse . dropWhile (== '\n') . reverse

runP :: Parser a -> String -> Either ParseError a
runP p = runParser (p <* eof) defaultLayoutEnv "" . trim
```

If I try to run it on input like

```
s = unlines [ "A = case B of"
            , " X -> Y Z"
            , "C = D"
            ]
```

via `runP (laidout binding) s`, it fails on the application `Y Z`:

```
(line 2, column 10):
expecting space or semi-colon
```

However, if I change the definition of `term` to

```
term = foldl1 App <$> many1 part
```

then it doesn't stop parsing the term at the start of the (unindented!) third line, leading to

```
(line 3, column 4):
expecting semi-colon
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has to do with that `name` already eliminates the following space, so the `sepBy1` in the definition of `term` doesn't see it.

Consider these simplified versions of `term`:

```
term0 = foldl1 App <$> (Var <$> name) `sepBy1` space

term1 = foldl1 App <$> (Var <$> name') `sepBy1` space

name' = (:) <$> upper <*> many alphaNum

term3 = foldl1 App <$> many (Var <$> name)
```

Then:

```
runP term0 "A B C"   -- fails
runP term1 "A B C"   -- succeeds
runP term3 "A B C"   -- succeeds
```

I think part of the solution is to define

```
part = [ caseBlock, Var <$> name' ]
```

where `name'` is as above. However, there are still some issues.

Comment: Promising, but... with this approach, if I want to reinstate the `caseBlock` (which requires using `term1` unless I misunderstood something), parsing now fails on the `o` of `of`, in `case X of`. I guess because the term `X` doesn't consume its trailing space now, and so it is parsed as an application of `X` to `of`...